# Java TreeMap containsKey invariably returning true?

Tags: java, treemap, containskey

I'm writing a Java program that's using the TreeMap interface, and I'm having a problem with containsKey. It is returning true even when I give containsKey something that I know for certain is not in the TreeMap.

What could be the cause of this?

Thanks so much in advance.

--

Edit: I am writing a program that counts the occurrences of words in a text file. The words are parsed and each one is a new instance of a class. In these classes, the equals and hashCode methods are overridden because the words need to be treated as equals even if they are different objects.

The field "text" a String that contains the text of the word.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){   
   Word temp = ((Word)obj);  
   return this.text.equals(temp.text);  
}

public int hashCode(){  
   return this.text.hashCode();  
}

public int compareTo (Object x) { 
   Word temp = ((Word)x);

   if(this.text.compareTo(temp.text) < 0){
      return -1;
   }
   else if (this.text.equals(temp.text)){
      return 0;
   }
   else {
      return 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some example code ?

Comment: And your compareTo implementation?

Comment: Hmm... well, that *looks* okay (although it would be simpler just to return `this.text.compareTo(temp.text))`) - do you have a short but complete program which demonstrates it failing?

Comment: TreeMap doesn't actually use equals() or hashCode(). It uses compareTo() exclusively.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you're using a key type which has an incorrect implementation of `equals` (and probably `hashCode` too), or that the comparator isn't consistent with `equals`. I can't think of any other reason off the top of my head.

If you can product a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, we could confirm this.